# How to fetch values from Ignite Cache while giving key in regular expression?

Tags: ignite

There is format for key in my Ignite cache like

```
igniteCache.put("CACHE_1.2.3", someValue1)
igniteCache.put("CACHE_1.2.4", someValue2)
igniteCache.put("CACHE_2.2.3", someValue3)
```

How to get the values where key matches regex like "CACHE_1.*.*"
I am expecting the output
[someValue1, someValue2]

Can someone help to solve this?

Comment: Regex like "CACHE_1.*.*"

Answer (score 2):

This effect can by achieved by using an SQL request with LIKE predicate.

Consider the following example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people(name varchar PRIMARY KEY, age int);

INSERT INTO people (name, age) values('Bob', 21);
INSERT INTO people (name, age) values('George', 30);
INSERT INTO people (name, age) values('Georgiy', 31);

SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'Georg%'
```

The final select results in two rows with `name` column starting from "Georg".

So, you'll need to either switch to using SQL to define the data schema, or configure [query entities](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/cplus-schema-and-indexes) for your cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [ScanQuery](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#scan-queries) with predicate:

```
igniteCache.query(new ScanQuery<String, Integer>((k, v) -> k.startsWith("CACHE_1")));
```

Comment: Too bad, what does it say?

Comment: I had a problem with IgniteCacheConfiguration I fixed that. It worked what you suggested. Thanks!